# trying to get absolute file path's from relative path's from CLI

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
cd "C:\path\to\directory\" >nul & echo %CD%
```

Say I run that in `C:\dir`. I'd expect it to output `C:\path\to\directory` since that's what it does if I run each command individually and in succession. But it doesn't do that. When the two commands are sorta concatenated together it outputs the current path - eg. `C:\dir`.

Any ideas why? Alternatively, any ideas as to how I can get the full path from a relative path via the CLI?

Comment: Relative to what? To %cd%?

Comment: To the current directory. ie. say you're in `C:\path\to\directory\`. You do `cd ..\..` and then "`echo %CD%` and you'll get `C:\path\`. But `cd "..\.." >nul & echo %CD%` isn't giving me the same thing and I want to know why.

Comment: This is actually a feature. You can do `cd \somewhere\else & do something & cd %CD%` and it will change to the other directory, do something, then change back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concenate two commands they act like a code block and all %variables% can't change their value. You have to use delayed expansion:

```
@ECHO OFF & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd "C:\path\to\directory\" >nul & echo !CD!
```

Output will be:

```
C:\path\to\directory
```